# How to Fix an Error PHP Fatal error: Out of memory?

Tags: php, nginx, memory, out-of-memory, fastcgi

I do not have a server running, error 502 within 25 minutes, I see the following in the logs:

```
2017/08/19 19:36:30 [error] 7652#0: *978 upstream sent unexpected FastCGI record: 3 while reading response header from upstream, client: 207.46.13.158, server: vamdodoma.ru, request: "GET /catalog/2-mestnye-divany/S39861885.html/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/php-nginx/14617404421463.sock/socket:", host: "vamdodoma.ru"
2017/08/19 19:36:31 [error] 7651#0: *622 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 262144) (tried to allocate 8589938688 bytes) in Unknown on line 0" while reading response header from upstream, client: 46.237.19.175, server: vamdodoma.ru, request: "GET /api/app.getCities HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/php-nginx/14617404421463.sock/socket:", host: "vamdodoma.ru"
2017/08/19 19:36:31 [error] 7651#0: *622 upstream sent unexpected FastCGI record: 3 while reading response header from upstream, client: 46.237.19.175, server: vamdodoma.ru, request: "GET /api/app.getCities HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/php-nginx/14617404421463.sock/socket:", host: "vamdodoma.ru"
```

Server PHP, NGINX, MySQL

In php.ini memory_limit = 48000M

Why is not enough memory available?

Comment: Without code, it's really hard to tell. You can use XDebug to profile your site a bit and see where the logjam is coming from, but it's really something you're going to have to check. Often, it comes from trying to output a large object.

Comment: 8589938688 / (1024 *1024 * 1024) = 8GB. Your php code tried to allocate 8GB of memory. I don't think anyone cares what you set `memory_limit = 48000M` but if you need 8GB of memory to run a script then you are doing something wrong